# How to nest logic in a case block of sql

Tags: sql, select, subquery

I have a table with containing test scores for students. There can be more than 1 score per test type. So student A, can have multiple scores for Test 1, one score for Test 2, etc.

Basically, if a student has only test score for Test 1, I want to do x. And if a student has multiple test scores for Test 1, I want to do y. How can I accomplish this?

My query so far is:

```
SELECT A.*
  ,T.TestType
  ,CASE
    WHEN T.TestType = 'test_1' THEN T.MessageLocation
  END AS Loc
FROM #Person A
LEFT JOIN #TestScores T ON A.TestID = T.ID
```

But what I want to do (pseudo-code) is:

```
SELECT A.*
  ,T.TestType
  ,CASE
    -- when count(test_1) = 1 THEN T.MessageLocation
    -- when count(test_1) > 1 THEN
    -- for each row T.AltMessageLocation
  END AS Loc
FROM #Person A
LEFT JOIN #TestScores T ON A.TestID = T.ID
```

Comment: Why are you joining on `TestId`?  I would expect the join on the person id.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate the data by ResrID and TestType first, the add the result join with your existing query. Assuming you are using SQL Server, it will be something like:

```
;WITH cteTestNum(
  SELECT T.ID,T.TestType,COUNT(*) AS TestNum
  FROM #Person A
  INNER JOIN #TestScores T 
  ON A.TestID = T.ID
  GROUP BY T.ID,T.TestType
)
SELECT A.*
  ,T.TestType
  ,CASE
    WHEN ISNULL(N.TestType,N'') = 'test_1' AND ISNULL(N.TestNum,0)>1 THEN T.MessageLocation
    WHEN ISNULL(N.TestType,N'') = 'test_1' AND ISNULL(N.TestNum,0)>1 THEN T.AltMessageLocation
    ELSE N'' -- no tests
  END AS Loc
FROM #Person A
LEFT JOIN #TestScores T
ON A.TestID = T.ID
LEFT JOIN cteTestNum N
ON N.ID=T.ID
AND N.TestType=T.TestType;
```